# Install SimpleElastix for Python3 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, itk, elastix, simpleitk

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.6, trying to install the SimpleElastix extension of SimpleITK. I have been following the instructions [here](http://simpleelastix.readthedocs.io/GettingStarted.html). After I got it to work, it turned out the extension seems to be only included in SimpleITK when I use Python 2.7, but not when I use Python 3.6 in the sense that when I try

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
resultImage = sitk.Elastix(sitk.ReadImage("fixedImage.nii"), sitk.ReadImage("movingImage.nii"))
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'SimpleITK' has no attribute 'Elastix'
```

I have found this [suggestion](https://github.com/rcasero/pysto/wiki/Build-and-install-SimpleElastix-for-python-3.x) but have not been able to get it to work on my Mac.

Thanks for any advice,

TomD

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this link to install:https://simpleelastix.readthedocs.io/GettingStarted.html#compiling-on-linux

Be care for the last python install, I use Ubuntu16.04, and my python is under my user's anaconda, you should use the python install without the sudo, but it will not work. So you need to change the permission of build folder to 777 before run the python setup.py install